# Is there option to turn off 3D on Heroes of Might and Magic V?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-5

I don't have good graphic card. So its quite slow, but is there option to turn off 3D on Heroes of Might and Magic V?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can only tinker with the graphic quality, but not somehow turn off 3D.

In general:

- "Turning off 3D" means that there basically should be another version of all the game art. **Very few** games support such a feature, I bet no more than a dozen.
- I recommend trying to lower the graphics quality (including lowering the resolution), it should help speed things up.

Comment: I bet not even one - that would be an *enormous* time sink for little-to-no benefit.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Civilization V has a 2D "Strategic View" which can be turned on and off mid game.

Answer (score 4):

Did you play Heroes of Might and magic III? It's 2D, it looks nice and gameplay is very similar.